# How to prepare a mongodb query with Golang?

Tags: mongodb, go

I have an array of objects with values for different  attributes. I cannot handle the scenario of having different values for same attributes in the object array in Golang. How can I prepare the mongodb query dynamically with or operator in such a scenario using Golang?

[{attribute: A1, value :X},{attribute:A1, value: Y},{attribute:A2 , value:Z},{attribute :A3, value :M}]

Answer (score 0):

First see Mongo DB is properly installed. MongoDB must be properly installed and running on the server making the Golang API calls. Type mongod into a terminal window to obtain information on the MongoDB daemon processes.

First get the following package:

```
go get gopkg.in/oleiade/reflections.v1
```

Golang must be installed and the MongoDB project directory must be in Golang’s $GOPATH . Confirm both are installed and working with the following command:

```
go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo
```

Execute the folloing command to import the packages to allow MongoDB to create BSON filters, queries and unmarshaled strings in the main() function:

```
package main

import (
"context" // manage multiple requests
"encoding/json" // Use JSON encoding for bson. M string
"fmt" // Println() function
"log"
"reflect" // get an object type

// import 'mongo-go-driver' package libraries
"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive" // for BSON ObjectID
"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
"go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)
```

Execute the following script to use Golang’s struct datatype to map the MongoDB fields for the collection’s documents:

```
type MongoFields struct {
Key string `json:"key,omitempty"`
// ObjectId() or objectid. ObjectID is deprecated--use primitive instead
ID primitive. ObjectID `bson:"_id, omitempty"`

// Use these field tags so Golang knows how to map MongoDB fields
// `bson:"string field" json:"string field"`
StringField string `bson:"string field" json:"string field"`
IntField int `bson:"int field" json:"int field"`
BoolField bool `bson:"bool field" json:"bool field"`
}
```

**How to view a collection’s document fields in ‘Mongo Shell’**
Enter the following script in Mongo Shell to confirm the exact format of the fields:

```
mongo shell
use SomeDatabase
db["Some Collection"]
db["Some Collection"].findOne()
```

***I hope this would be helpful***